# Simple Site Stat script not gathering data from file, I have an almost exact script that works

Tags: php, file, view, ip

I made a script a while ago that wrote to a file, I did the same thing here, only added a part to read the file and write it again. What I am trying to achive is quite simple, but the problem is eluding me, I am trying to make my script write to a file basically holding the following information

```
views:{viewcount}
date-last-visited:{MM/DD/YYYY}
last-ip:{IP-Adress}
```

Now I have done a bit of research, and tried several methods to reading the data, none have returned anything. My current code is as follows.

```
<?php
$filemade = 0;

if(!file_exists("stats")){
    if(!mkdir("stats")){
        exit();
    }
    $filemade = 1;
}
echo $filemade;
$hwrite = fopen("stats/statistics.txt", 'w');

$icount = 0;

if(filemade == 0){

    $data0 = file_get_contents("stats/statistics.txt");

    $data2 = explode("\n", $data0);

    $data1 = $data_1[0];

    $ccount = explode(":", data1);

    $icount = $ccount[1] + 1;

    echo "<br>icount:".$icount."<br>";
    echo "data1:".$data1."<br>";
    echo "ccount:".$ccount."<br>";
    echo "ccount[0]:".$ccount1[0]."<br>";
    echo "ccount[1]:".$ccount1[1]."<br>";

}

$date = getdate();

$ip=@$REMOTE_ADDR; 

fwrite($hwrite, "views:" . $icount . "\nlast-viewed:" . $date[5] . "/" . $date[3] . $date[2] . "/" . $date[6] . "\nlast-ip:" . $ip);

fclose($hwrite);
?>
```

the result is always:

```
views:1
last-viewed://
last-ip:
```

the views never go up, the date never works, and the IP address never shows.

I have looked at many sources before finally deciding to ask, I figured I'd get more relevant information this way.

Looking forward to some replies. PHP is my newest language, and so I don't know much.

What I have tried.

I have tried:

```
$handle_read = fopen("stats/statistics.txt", "r");//make a new file handle in read mode
$data = fgets($handle_read);//get first line
$data_array = explode(":", $data);//split first line by ":"
$current_count = $data_array[1];//get second item, the value
```

and

```
$handle_read = fopen("stats/statistics.txt", "r");//make a new file handle in read mode
$pre_data = fread($handle_read, filesize($handle_read));//read all the file data
$pre_data_array = explode("\n", $pre_data);//split the file by lines
$data = pre_data_array[0];//get first line
$data_array = explode(":", $data);//split first line by ":"
$current_count = $data_array[1];//get second item, the value
```

I have also tried split instead of explode, but I was told split is deprecated and explode is up-to-date.

Any help would be great, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
<?php
if(!file_exists("stats")){
  if(!mkdir("stats")) die("Could not create folder");
}
// file() returns an array of file contents or false
$data = file("stats/statistics.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
if(!$data){
  if(!touch("stats/statistics.txt")) die("Could not create file");
  // Default Values
  $data = array("views:0", "date-last-visited:01/01/2000", "last-ip:0.0.0.0");
}
// Update the data
foreach($data as $key => $val){
  // Limit explode to 2 chunks because we could have
  // IPv6 Addrs (e.x ::1)
  $line = explode(':', $val, 2);
  switch($key){
    case 0:
      $line[1]++;
      break;
    case 1:
      $line[1] = date('m/d/Y');
      break;
    case 2:
      $line[1] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
      break;
  }
  $data[$key] = implode(':', $line);
  echo $data[$key]. "<br />";
}
// Write the data back into the file
if(!file_put_contents("stats/statistics.txt", implode(PHP_EOL, $data))) die("Could not write file");
?>
```

Comment: that looks like more advanced php than I'm into so far, so if you could just explain better what each part does. I understand it al;l after going through it a few tiems, and it's interesting, I like the swich and case method, didn't think of using it like that, but then again I didn't quite understand the => until now, which I'm still not sure I do, is it basically adding 1 to key each time, and storing the actual value in val? And why is the / there in <br>? XHTML and HTML work fine without the "/". I did not know about the file() function, thank you for that, a lot. I'll try it. thank you.

Comment: No problem. As for some explanation: In an array, $x => $y represents the key name ($x) and the associated value ($y) in the array. As for the switch/case, it is easier than writing out if statements, but is only possible because we know **exactly** how many lines there are and the specific order. At the end of the loop, we set the new values to the original array key (in essence replacing the data). As for the / in the line break, it's just a habit of mine for clean coding, and XHTML Strict does require it to be self closing.

Comment: thank you very much for the explanation, I'm not far into php and so this really helps. Now that I have this in an external php file, I need to find a way to run it on my page loading. I may be able to use include_once inside the body's onLoad="" attribute, but idk. thank you.

Comment: dang, my host doesn't seem to allow me access to the body tag, so I can't even use the onLoad attribute...

Comment: The body's onLoad property us usually used for Javascript. If you just include or require this file at the top of every php page, it should do just fine. One thing to watch out for is the path to statistics.txt. Currently it is relative. You should consider making it absolute to make sure you don't end up with random files everywhere.

Comment: problem is that my home page is NOT a PHP file and is an HTML file, I am trying to track how many people view my homepage. My pages are all in a sub directory, and a PHP file handles them all, but my web-host encrypts that PHP file, so here's what it looks like **¡ò˜>vÈÝTÑø4¿›Ã˜žQ2àE`?ïô,bQèÇ‘ðÏ¸|jSçb{‰…iÂ s˜=ðA…'
L€ùŒÎŠ¹WÈT¿** yeah, good luck for me to find out how to require the PHP file in that... So I'm trying to find a way in HTML to call the php script on load, and ONLY on my homepage, not any other page, or I'd be better off making a script per page.

Comment: I think I found a solution however, I will make a javascript change the doccument url to my php script, and have the php script include_once my homepage, however that may cause an infinite loop... so probably not a good idea... I'll figure something out.

Comment: Reading the information you have given me here, It seems to me that your best option is really to rewrite this function and use some AJAX to solve your problem.

Comment: I h8 AJAX, and know less than php. I think I may know ways to do this, I think I may use an iframe to call an html script that actually calls the php script, there's one way, I've also heard that you can use the img tag with a script url, because it'll make the page request that url, even though you'd then basically get the red x... so there are ways to do it, I just got to find a good one. Thank you for all your help so far.